# How to set timeout in Retrofit library?

Tags: java, android, timeout, retrofit

I am using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) library in my app, and I'd like to set a timeout of 60 seconds. Does Retrofit have some way to do this?

I set Retrofit this way:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setServer(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
    .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
    .build();
```

How can I set the timeout?

Answer (score 366, accepted):

You can set timeouts on the underlying HTTP client. If you don't specify a client, Retrofit will create one with default connect and read timeouts.  To set your own timeouts, you need to configure your own client and supply it to the `RestAdapter.Builder`.

An option is to use the [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) client, also from Square.

**1. Add the library dependency**

In the build.gradle, include this line:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:x.x.x'
```

*Where `x.x.x` is the desired library version.*

**2. Set the client**

For example, if you want to set a timeout of 60 seconds, do this way for Retrofit before version 2 and Okhttp before version 3 (***FOR THE NEWER VERSIONS, SEE THE EDITS***):

```
public RestAdapter providesRestAdapter(Gson gson) {
    final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    return new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
        .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
        .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))
        .build();
}
```

---

**EDIT 1**

For okhttp versions since `3.x.x`, you have to set the dependency this way:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:x.x.x'
```

And set the client using the builder pattern:

```
final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();
```

More info in [Timeouts](https://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/#timeouts-kt-java)

---

**EDIT 2**

Retrofit versions since `2.x.x` also uses the builder pattern, so change the return block above to this:

```
return new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(okHttpClient)
    .build();
```

If using a code like my `providesRestAdapter` method, then change the method return type to [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/).

More info in [Retrofit 2 — Upgrade Guide from 1.9](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-upgrade-guide-from-1-9)

---

ps: If your minSdkVersion is greater than 8, you can use `TimeUnit.MINUTES`:

```
okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

For more details about the units, see [TimeUnit](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html).

Comment: I do not see setReadTimeout in the new version of okhttp, any new ways of doing this?

Comment: I'm using okhttp3, and for me I've used this code:

 new okhttp3.OkHttpClient().newBuilder();
        okHttpClient.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        okHttpClient.writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        okHttpClient.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  new Retrofit.Builder()
   .client(okHttpClient.build())

Comment: @lucasddaniel You can use the edited answer and place the declared name of OkHttpClient to your Retrofit builder like this 
'Retrofit retrofitBuilderName = new Retrofit.Builder().
client(okttpclientName).
build();'

Comment: Where do you get the `gson` object which you passed to this method? I followed a [tutorial](http://www.androidwarriors.com/2015/08/retrofit-android-example-web-services.html) to get this far and I was doing `RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(url).build();` to create the `RestAdapter`. There isn't any `Gson` object in my class.; thought I do have the gson and converter-gson libraries included in my project.

Comment: @Solace I have thid method:     `public Gson providesGson() {
        return new GsonBuilder().create();
    }`. So I do this:  `Gson gson = module.providesGson();
        RestAdapter adapter = module.providesRestAdapter(gson);`. Where module is an instance of the the proper class that have all these methods

Comment: If you're using OkHttp3 you have to use `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.x.x'` in the gradle import like in the answer below by Teo

Answer (score 96):

These answers were outdated for me, so here's how it worked out.

Add OkHttp, in my case the version is `3.3.1`:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
```

Then before building your Retrofit, do this:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
    .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build();
return new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
    .client(okHttpClient)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
```

Comment: my bad, i was missing the ()

Comment: what will happen after that 60 seconds? Can we show any prompt right there?

Comment: @ArnoldBrown You retrofit call will fail which will call onFailure()

Answer (score 11):

```
public class ApiClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();

    public static void clear() {
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            retrofit = null;
        }
    }

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            if (retrofit == null) {

                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                        .setLenient()
                        .create();

                OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                        .connectTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .build();


                retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .client(okHttpClient)
                        .baseUrl(Constants.WEB_SERVICE)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                        .build();
            }
            return retrofit;
        }

    }

    public static RequestBody plain(String content) {
        return getRequestBody("text/plain", content);
    }

    public static RequestBody getRequestBody(String type, String content) {
        return RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(type), content);
    }
}

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("architect/project_list_Design_files")
Call<DesignListModel> getProjectDesign(
        @Field("project_id") String project_id);


@Multipart
@POST("architect/upload_design")
Call<BoqListModel> getUpLoadDesign(
        @Part("user_id") RequestBody user_id,
        @Part("request_id") RequestBody request_id,
        @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> image_file,
        @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> design_upload_doc);


private void getMyProjectList()
{

    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<MyProjectListModel> call = apiService.getMyProjectList("",Sorting,latitude,longitude,Search,Offset+"",Limit);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<MyProjectListModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MyProjectListModel> call, Response<MyProjectListModel> response) {
            try {
                Log.e("response",response.body()+"");

            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("onResponse: ", e.toString());
                           }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MyProjectListModel> call, Throwable t)
        {
            Log.e( "onFailure: ",t.toString());
                   }
    });
}

// file upload

private void getUpload(String path,String id)
    {

        ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        MultipartBody.Part GalleryImage = null;
        if (path!="")
        {
            File file = new File(path);
            RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
            GalleryImage = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), reqFile);
        }

        RequestBody UserId = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), id);
        Call<uplod_file> call = apiService.geUplodFileCall(UserId,GalleryImage);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<uplod_file>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<uplod_file> call, Response<uplod_file> response) {
                try {
                    Log.e("response",response.body()+"");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.body().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e("onResponse: ", e.toString());
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<uplod_file> call, Throwable t)
            {
                Log.e( "onFailure: ",t.toString());
            }
        });
    }

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
```

Comment: Please some expaination to your answer.

Answer (score 11):

**In Kotlin :**

At first you should create a `OkHttp client` and add in Retrofit builder

```
fun create(): Retrofit { 

        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()


        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }
}
```

Comment: just lack  .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS). anyways this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

##### In Kotlin you can Configure timeout for `retrofit2` by

create OkHttpClient object (The default value is **10** seconds)

```
val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build()
```

Then add this object to your retrofit builder

```
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
    .client(okHttpClient)
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()
```

And import `TimeUnit` from this package

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using **Retrofit 1.9** to obtain a **XML**.

```
public class ServicioConexionRetrofitXML {

    public static final String API_BASE_URL = new GestorPreferencias().getPreferencias().getHost();
    public static final long tiempoMaximoRespuestaSegundos = 60;
    public static final long tiempoMaximoLecturaSegundos = 100;
    public static final OkHttpClient clienteOkHttp = new OkHttpClient();


    private static RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder().
            setEndpoint(API_BASE_URL).
            setClient(new OkClient(clienteOkHttp)).setConverter(new SimpleXMLConverter());


    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        clienteOkHttp.setConnectTimeout(tiempoMaximoRespuestaSegundos, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        clienteOkHttp.setReadTimeout(tiempoMaximoLecturaSegundos, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        RestAdapter adapter = builder.build();
        return adapter.create(serviceClass);
    }

}
```

If you are using Retrofit 1.9.0 and okhttp 2.6.0, add to your Gradle file.

```
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0'
    // Librería de retrofit para XML converter (Simple) Se excluyen grupos para que no entre
    // en conflicto.
    compile('com.squareup.retrofit:converter-simplexml:1.9.0') {
        exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax'
    }
```

Note: If you need to fetch a **JSON**, just remove from code above.

```
.setConverter(new SimpleXMLConverter())
```

Answer (score 1):

For Retrofit1.9 with OkHttp3 users, here is the solution,

```
.setClient(new Ok3Client(new OkHttpClient.Builder().readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ApiModule {
    public WebService apiService(Context context) {
        String mBaseUrl = context.getString(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? R.string.local_url : R.string.live_url);

        HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY : HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE);

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                //.addNetworkInterceptor(networkInterceptor)
                .build();

        return new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(mBaseUrl)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build().create(WebService.class);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this example

https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1557

Here we set custom url client connection client before before we build API rest service implementation.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import retrofit.Endpoint
import retrofit.RestAdapter
import retrofit.client.Request
import retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient
import retrofit.converter.GsonConverter


class ClientBuilder {

    public static <T> T buildClient(final Class<T> client, final String serviceUrl) {
        Endpoint mCustomRetrofitEndpoint = new CustomRetrofitEndpoint()


        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create()
        RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(mCustomRetrofitEndpoint)
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
            .setClient(new MyUrlConnectionClient())
        RestAdapter restAdapter = builder.build()
        return restAdapter.create(client)
    }
}

 public final class MyUrlConnectionClient extends UrlConnectionClient {
        @Override
        protected HttpURLConnection openConnection(Request request) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = super.openConnection(request);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(15 * 1000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(30 * 1000);
            return connection;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class ApiClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();

    public static void clear() {
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            retrofit = null;
        }
    }

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            if (retrofit == null) {

                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                        .setLenient()
                        .create();

                OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                        .connectTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .build();

                // Log.e("jjj", "=" + (MySharedPreference.getmInstance().isEnglish() ? Constant.WEB_SERVICE : Constant.WEB_SERVICE_ARABIC));
                retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .client(okHttpClient)
                        .baseUrl(Constants.WEB_SERVICE)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                        .build();
            }
            return retrofit;
        }`enter code here`

    }

    public static RequestBody plain(String content) {
        return getRequestBody("text/plain", content);
    }

    public static RequestBody getRequestBody(String type, String content) {
        return RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(type), content);
    }
}


-------------------------------------------------------------------------


    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!