# How to set timeout in Retrofit-2.0+ android

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

**I referred [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29380845/1083093) but I can't seem to implement for mine**

**I am using**

```
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
```

**I am using the below code, How to set timeout for this !**

```
public class ApiClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = Constants.BaseURL;
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Configure [OkHttpClient](http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Retrofit.Builder.html#client-okhttp3.OkHttpClient-) for timeout option. Then use this as client for `Retrofit.Builder`.

```
final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build();
```

[Use this `okHttpClient` for Retrofit#Builder](http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Retrofit.Builder.html#client-okhttp3.OkHttpClient-)

```
Retrofit.Builder()
    .client(okHttpClient);
```

[Official OkHttp documentation about timeout is here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#timeouts)

Comment: what is the difference between connect, write and read time out? thank you :)

Comment: Connect Timeout - The maximum time in making the initial connection to the server. Write Timeout - The maximum time you allow to write (send) the request data to the service. Read Timeout - The time you wait for the response. @ladytoky0 Hope this helps you :)

Comment: thank you very much! so much clear now :D

Answer (score 8):

try below code, it sét `timeout` is 20 seconds and `readTimeout` is 30 seconds

```
 private OkHttpClient getRequestHeader() {
        OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        httpClient.setConnectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        httpClient.setReadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        return httpClient;
    }
```

Then

```
public class ApiClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = Constants.BaseURL;
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(getRequestHeader())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm curious why you named your method `getRequestHeader()`?  I'd suggest `getHttpClient()` would be a better name.

Comment: I am getting setConnectTimeout() & setReadTimeout() can't be resolved. Imported package okhttp3.OkHttpClient. Please help me, i am new to retrofit/okhttp

Answer (score 1):

**I have used bellow like in Kotlin with MVVM Model..**

```
var okHttpClient: OkHttpClient? = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build()

private val api = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(baseurl)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
    .client(okHttpClient)
    .build()
    .create(Api::class.java);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0" retrofit version > 2 then you try this one:

```
private OkHttpClient getRequestHeader() 
{
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();

    return okHttpClient;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

##### In Kotlin you can Configure timeout for Retrofit by

Create OkHttpClient object with time in seconds (The default value is **10** seconds)

```
private val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build()
```

Then use this object for Retrofit Builder

```
private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
    .client(okHttpClient)
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()
```

And import these

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import retrofit2.Retrofit
```