# SocketTimeoutException in Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp, socket-timeout-exception

I am trying to **POST** request to server for fetch data but sometime It's occure `SocketTimeoutException`!

I used `Ok3Client` to resolve it but I facing the same Exception   How can I resolve it?

My code is below

```
public void getNormalLogin() {
        if (mProgressDialog == null) {
            mProgressDialog = ViewUtils.createProgressDialog(mActivity);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        } else {
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK != null && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 13) {
            restadapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(HOST).setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL).setClient(new Ok3Client(new OkHttpClient())).build();
            mApi = restadapter.create(Api.class);
            mApi.SignIn(etEmail.getText().toString(), etPassword.getText().toString(), new Callback<ArrayList<SignUpMainBean>>() {
                @Override
                public void success(ArrayList<SignUpMainBean> signUpMainBeen, Response response) {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    LOGD("Status:: ::", String.valueOf(response.getStatus()));
                    LOGD("Code:: ::", String.valueOf(signUpMainBeen.get(0).getCode()));
                    if (signUpMainBeen != null && signUpMainBeen.size() > 0) {
                        if (signUpMainBeen.get(0).getCode() == 1) {

                            for (int i = 0; i < signUpMainBeen.size(); i++) {
                                for (int j = 0; j < signUpMainBeen.get(i).getResult().size(); j++) {
                                    showToast(mActivity, getString(R.string.you_have_successfully_login), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                    LOGD("Success", "Success");                                                                         
                                   finish();
                                    SignIn.mActivity.finish();
                                }
                            }

                        } else if (signUpMainBeen.get(0).getCode() == 0) {
                            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                            showToast(mActivity, getString(R.string.invalid_email_password), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            LOGD("Invalid email or password", "Invalid email or password");
                        } else if (signUpMainBeen.get(0).getCode() == -1) {
                            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                            showToast(mActivity, getString(R.string.your_account_is_inactive), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            LOGD("Your account is inactive", "Your account is inactive");
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    showToast(mActivity, getString(R.string.can_not_connect_to_server), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    LOGD("Failure", "Failure");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

My Error Log is

```
D/Retrofit: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:532)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:40)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:255)
at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:139)
at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:211)
at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:306)
at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:300)
at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:196)
at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(Http1xStream.java:185)
at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponseHeaders(Http1xStream.java:126)
at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:723)
at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.access$200(HttpEngine.java:81)
at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:708)
at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:563)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:241)
at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:198)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:160)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:57)
at com.jakewharton.retrofit.Ok3Client.execute(Ok3Client.java:40)
at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:326)
at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608499/getting-java-net-sockettimeoutexception-connection-timed-out-in-android)

Comment: @Komal how to stop crash? Did you find any solution? Please share..

Answer (score 84):

Increase the time if the fetching is taking more time use this code it worked for me

```
 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(100,TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("yourbaseurl").client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new  Gson())).build();
```

hay this is a work around not the best practice , from comments down,
 Back end should not take this long and user must be notified with error or try again message

Comment: This doesn't prevent the app crash in our application. Is there a way to handle this without having the app crash?

Comment: what Exception do you get is it Null Pointer

Comment: Your application will try to load the content even if the server is responding after a long time - It's a workaround, not the solution :)

Comment: Even for a workaround this is bad.  Increasing the Timeout will do nothing to solve the issue.  There is no way to prevent a Timeout, it will always happen wether the API takes time to respond or connectivity is bad.  Best bet is to catch this and prompt to the user something went wrong and ask them to try again.

If the actual API calls takes time and the bottleneck is on the backend side you may want to consider looking into that.  APIs should be fast and anything more than 10s where the API is the culprit is just bad.

Answer (score 42):

Preventing `SocketTimeoutException` is beyond our limit...One way to effectively handle it is to define a `connection timeout`

Example for

> retrofit 1.9.0

```
restadapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(HOST).setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL).setClient(new OkHttpClient()
                .setReadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .setConnectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).build();
```

> retrofit 2.0.0

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.setConnectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
client.setReadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client)
        .build();
```

> retrofit 2.4.0

```
// setting custom timeouts
    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new Builder();
    client.connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    if (retrofit == null) {
      retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
          .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
          .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
          .client(client.build())
          .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
  }
```

Comment: Can not resolve method of readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                and connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).build();

Comment: Are you using `'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'` @Komal

Comment: I'm using compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.0'

Comment: I also tried 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1' but still as it is!!! Any other idea about it?

Comment: @Komal You are using retrofit right ?What is the version of it.

Comment: I used these both 
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit1-okhttp3-client:1.0.2'

Comment: @Komal I gave you the example for retrofit 2.0 .Please check my updated answer I have changed.

Comment: Thanks @Soham but still setReadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS) not resolved method

Comment: @Komal please check again my answer.I forgot mostly the code for retrofit 1.9.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122166/discussion-between-komal-and-soham).

Comment: @Komal Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29380845/3967525)

Comment: How  to set the timeout in Retrofit `2.1.0`?

Comment: Set it on the builder and not on the client. OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

Answer (score 13):

I'm facing the same issue with some request. Usually get this when there's an active request and got `SocketTimeoutException` due to got disconnected from the network. After that, same request always throws `SocketTimeoutException`.

I built my `OkHttpClient` using the code below as suggested in "[java.net.SocketTimeoutException from HTTP/2 connection leaves dead okhttp clients in pool](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3146)":

```
val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .cache(cache)
    .readTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .connectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .connectionPool(ConnectionPool(0, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
    .protocols(listOf(Protocol.HTTP_1_1))
```

Setting the `connectionPool` and `protocols` will fix `SocketTimeoutException` caused by Timeouts.

This is a temporary fix and hopefully will get resolved in future versions of `OkHttp` used by `Retrofit`.

Comment: Adding protocol HTTP_1_1 worked! Thanks @philip. This is what I got from sourcecode- /**
   * An obsolete plaintext framing that does not use persistent sockets by default.
   */
  HTTP_1_0("http/1.0"),

  /**
   * A plaintext framing that includes persistent connections.
   *
   * <p>This version of OkHttp implements <a href="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230">RFC
   * 7230</a>, and tracks revisions to that spec.
   */
  HTTP_1_1("http/1.1"),

Comment: This saved me from the hours of waste. Thank you so much dude and the dude who gave this solution to you.

Answer (score 2):

```
val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
.cache(cache)
.readTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.connectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.connectionPool(ConnectionPool(0, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
.protocols(listOf(Protocol.HTTP_1_1))
```

ConnectionPool(0, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES) is key code, set maxIdleConnections as 0, to avoid the SocketTimeoutException by multiplex. this case is easy to happen when locking/unlocking the screen.

Answer (score 1):

It's works for me to catch and throw a new IOException

```java
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        Response response = null;
        try {
            response = chain.proceed(request);
        }catch (SocketTimeoutException e){
            throw new IOException();
        }
        String url = request.url().url().toString();
        if (existInWhiteList(url)) {
            return response;
        }
        return logResponse(response);
    }
```

and you can add your own info in this `new IOException()`;

Answer (score 0):

A possible resolution for this is make sure that you sending the correct request body to the server. For example, does the server need `x-www-form-urlencoded` or `form-data` in its request body? A simple way to test this is using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).