# Android Retrofit 2 Custom JSON request

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I am developing an application in i am using retrofit 2.
My request JSON is as below

```
{
    "FirstName":"ABC",
    "LastName":"XYZ",
    "Email":"abc@xyz.com",
    "Password":123456",
    "PhoneNo":"1234567890",
    "Country":"1",
    "State":"1",
    "City":"1",
    "Town":"YYYYYY",
    "Details":[{
        "Education":"BE",
        "Sports":"Cricket",
        "Hobby":"TV" 
    }]
}
```

My API service call is as below

```
public interface APIService {
    @POST("/signup")
    Call<SignUpResponseModel> signUp(@Body SignUpRequestParent body);
}
```

My API Util class is as below

```
public class ApiUtils {
    private ApiUtils() {}
    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://URL/";

    public static APIService getAPIService() {
        return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(APIService.class);
    }
}
```

My Retrofit client class is as follows:

```
public class RetrofitClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .client(getHeader())
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

    public static OkHttpClient getHeader() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .addNetworkInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Request request = null;
                        Request original = chain.request();
                        // Request customization add request headers
                        Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                            .addHeader("Authorization", "auth")
                        request = requestBuilder.build();
                        return chain.proceed(request);
                    }
                }).build();
        return okClient;
    }
}
```

My request model classes are as follows:

```
public class SignUpRequestParent {
    final String FirstName;
    final String LastName;
    final String Email;
    final String Password;
    final String PhoneNo;
    final String Country;
    final String State;
    final String City;
    final String Town;
    final List<SignUpRequestChild> Details;
    public SignUpRequestParent(String FirstName, String LastName, String Email, String Password, String PhoneNo, String Country, String State, String City, String Town, List<SignUpRequestChild> Details) {
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
        this.Email = Email;
        this.Password = Password;
        this.PhoneNo = PhoneNo;
        this.Country = Country;
        this.State = State;
        this.City = City;
        this.Town = Town;
        this.Details = Details;
    }
}

public class SignUpRequestChild {
    final String Education;
    final String Sports;
    final String Hobby;

    public SignUpRequestChild(String Education, String Sports, String Hobby) {
        this.Education = Education;
        this.Sports = Sports;
        this.Hobby = Hobby;
    }
}
```

Below is the calling code of web service where i am getting **error**.

```
mAPIService.signUp(new SignUpRequestParent(name, surName, email, password, mobileNumber, country, state, city, Town, new SignUpRequestChild(Education,Sports,Hobby))).enqueue(new Callback<SignUpResponseModel>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<SignUpResponseModel> call, Response<SignUpResponseModel> response) {
        if(response.isSuccessful()) {                                                                        
            Log.e("SignUpResponse", response.body().toString());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<SignUpResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("RetroFit", ""+t);
    }
});
```

The first line of calling code is giving the **error**. As i do not know how to **create the nested JSON array from classes.**

Please goude me what to do. And where i am wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please add the stack trace with the error?

Comment: Also the SignUpResponseModel definition

Comment: @cgomezmendez - I am not able to call. The error while coding is : Cast 11th parameter to Java.util.List. Or Change 11th parameter to method 'SignUpRequestParent' from List<SignUpRequestChild> to SignUpRequestChild.

Comment: I don't see an 11th parameter anywhere.

Comment: Sorry its 10th parameter.

Comment: You are expecting a list in the constructor but passing a SignUpRequestChild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think your problem is this you are doing this

```
mAPIService.signUp(new SignUpRequestParent(name, surName,
 email, password, mobileNumber, country, state, city,
  Town, new SignUpRequestChild(Education,Sports,Hobby))).enqueue(new Callback<SignUpResponseModel>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<SignUpResponseModel> call,
     Response<SignUpResponseModel> response) {
        if(response.isSuccessful()) {                                                                        
            Log.e("SignUpResponse", response.body().toString());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<SignUpResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("RetroFit", ""+t);
    }
});
```

but your

```
new SignUpRequestChild(Education,Sports,Hobby))
```

it's expected to be a list as per your constructor so you should really be doing this

```
List childs = new ArrayList<SignUpRequestChild>();
childs.add(new SignUpRequestChild(Education,Sports,Hobby)));
mAPIService.signUp(new SignUpRequestParent(name, surName,
 email, password, mobileNumber, country, state, city,
  Town, childs).enqueue(new Callback<SignUpResponseModel>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<SignUpResponseModel> call,
     Response<SignUpResponseModel> response) {
        if(response.isSuccessful()) {                                                                        
            Log.e("SignUpResponse", response.body().toString());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<SignUpResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("RetroFit", ""+t);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think your answer is working but now i am getting java.net.SocketTimeoutException.

Comment: You could try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39219094/sockettimeoutexception-in-retrofit

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a stack trace with the error. One thing I can see from skimming the code is that the SignUpRequestParent constructor accepts a list of SignUpRequestChild objects whereas you're passing a new SignUpRequestChild object when making the api call.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling it the wrong way, try this

Add this in your RetrofitClient Class

```
  public static APIService getService() {
    return getClient().create(APIService.class);
  }
```

Then to call it from anywhere

```
RetrofitClient.getService.someMethodHere().enqueue ...
```