# Android Retrofit 2.6.1 timeout frequently

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using **retrofit** in my android app, while i'm calling the api first time the api work fine but after some time (10-15 minutes) in same page it will give **java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timed out** or some time **java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SSL handshake timed out**.
While in postman the request work fine.

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                    .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build();

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
```

Comment: this is a problem from server-side, sometimes happen

Comment: Your code seems fine. must be server problem.

Comment: @hamidkeyhani i think the same but the request work fine in post man

Comment: see this answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/59259257/8399393