# What could be the reason for a SocketTimeoutException on android but not on Postman?

Tags: android, go, socket.io

I have a `Golang` server with an API created with the help of `gin` and `gorm`. It was working fine until recently when it's having some weird behavior. Before calling the API on my android app using `Retrofit`, I'd test it on `Postman`. Just yesterday, I tried to call the login API to get the `JWT` token that is needed for the other API calls I'd need later on. On `Postman`, the login was working fine. But yesterday, the login doesn't work on the android app anymore because of the `SocketTimeoutException`. And I don't know what's causing that. On `Postman`, it said that it only took 10-ish seconds to finish the call, and I already increased the timeout of `Retrofit` to 180s using these lines of code:

```
private val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

and the issue still persist. I'm not sure if a code I added on the server before is causing this, but it isn't being called right now. It's some code for starting a socket server, which doesn't seem to really work right now for some reason(even though it's an official sample code from googollee). Here it is:

```
package helpers

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    socketio "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io"
    "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/engineio"
    "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/engineio/transport"
    "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/engineio/transport/polling"
    "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/engineio/transport/websocket"
)

const (
    SERVER_HOST = "localhost"
    SERVER_PORT = "60051"
    SERVER_TYPE = "tcp"
)

var allowOriginFunc = func(r *http.Request) bool {
    return true
}

func StartSocket() {

    server := socketio.NewServer(&engineio.Options{
        Transports: []transport.Transport{
            &polling.Transport{
                CheckOrigin: allowOriginFunc,
            },
            &websocket.Transport{
                CheckOrigin: allowOriginFunc,
            },
        },
    })

    server.OnConnect("/", func(s socketio.Conn) error {
        s.SetContext("")
        fmt.Println("connected:", s.ID())
        return nil
    })

    server.OnEvent("/", "notice", func(s socketio.Conn, msg string) {
        fmt.Println("notice:", msg)
        s.Emit("reply", "have "+msg)
    })

    server.OnError("/", func(s socketio.Conn, e error) {
        fmt.Println("meet error:", e)
    })

    server.OnDisconnect("/", func(s socketio.Conn, reason string) {
        fmt.Println("closed", reason)
    })

    go server.Serve()
    defer server.Close()

    http.Handle("/socket.io/", server)
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./asset")))

    fmt.Println("ScktSrv Serving at localhost:8000...")
    fmt.Print(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil))
}
```

Both the server and the emulator are running on my PC

UPDATE:
Here's what the android code looks like, it's kinda complex but it's basically just a `Retrofit` call:

```
val username = binding.txtUsername.text.toString()
val password = binding.txtPassword.text.toString()

val account = Account(" ", " ", " ", username, password, mutableListOf())

scope.launch {
    val inAPIDataResp = retFetchHlpr.fetchAPIData{ atlAPI.loginAccount(account) }
    
    //some code for processing the received response
}
```

//Retrofit endpoint setup

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("/account/login")
    suspend fun loginAccount(
        @Body data: Account
    ) : Response<AccountLoginResponse>
```

Here's the code from my helper class:

```
suspend fun <V> fetchAPIData(apiGetterFunc: suspend () -> Response<V>): V? {
    val actsResult: Response<V>?
    if( utils.isInternetAvailable(ctx) ){
        try{
            actsResult = apiGetterFunc.invoke()

            val respBody = retrofitErrorHandler(actsResult)
            if (respBody != null){
                return respBody
            }
        }catch (e: Exception){
            Log.e(TAG, "Retrofit Error: ${e.localizedMessage}")
        }
    }
    return null
}

private fun <T> retrofitErrorHandler(res: Response<T>): T {
    if (res.isSuccessful) {
        Log.d(TAG, "retrofitErrorHandler success: ${res.body()}")
        return res.body()!!
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "retrofitErrorHandler errMsg: ${res.errorBody().toString()}")
        throw Exception(res.errorBody().toString())
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Retrofit Error: failed to connect to /192.168.45.102 (port 5000) from
> /10.0.2.16 (port 54552) after 180000ms: isConnected failed: ETIMEDOUT
> (Connection timed out)

I tried connecting my PC and a tablet running the app to my phone's hotspot and I still get this error.

Comment: What does the Android code look like that is failing?

Comment: check any firewall, same thing happens if you test on device?

Comment: Yeah, emulator and device returns the same thing

Comment: But the API works fine before. I've been using it for a couple of months already. What firewall configuration should I be checking for this kind of issues?

Comment: `SERVER_PORT = "60051"` That does not match your error message.

Comment: Well, I mentioned above that those code aren't being used/called right now, so I don't think they are affecting the server

Answer (score 1):

I think I already found a solution. Adding `.protocols(listOf(Protocol.HTTP_1_1))` for the `OkHttpClient` seems to make `Retrofit` work fine again. Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59259257/10464730)

Comment: Just a small follow up question I guess, why does that code/configuration fix the issue?