# How to increase upload time for retrofit library in android

Tags: android, file-upload, timeout, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using retrofit library to upload file to server. When file was uploaded it shows `error:: timeout`. How to increase upload time so that I can upload full file in server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set timeout in Retrofit library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380844/how-to-set-timeout-in-retrofit-library)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here try this: In below code you will pass your custom OKHTTP client with your custom timeout

```
public class RetrofitClient {

    private static final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();


    public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

}
```

You also need this dependency:

`implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'// OKHTTP \\` Add this to your gradle file

Comment: How to handle file upload which takes more time? Can you help?

Comment: You can use multipart for file transfer. The web-service will maintain the connection until your file gets uploaded, unless there is a timeout from server side.

Comment: Can you help on this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61896772/how-to-handle-retrofit-socket-timeout-for-uploading-files-in-android-kotlin

Comment: more details in the question

Answer (score 2):

Add the following class in your project.

public class Api{

```
static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setLenient()
        .create();

public static Retrofit adapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL) //Set the Root URL
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .client(configureTimeouts())
        .build(); //Finally building the adapter

public static OkHttpClient configureTimeouts() {
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Set your timeout duration here.
            .writeTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
    return okHttpClient;
}
```

}

In the above configureTimeouts() function, you can set the duration after which the timeout occurs according to your requirements.

Also, don't forget to put these dependencies in your app level build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'    
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public RestAdapter providesRestAdapter(Gson gson) {
final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

return new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
    .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
    .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))
    .build();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS).connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.writeTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
private static Retrofit retrofit;

```
static {
    Builder addConverterFactory = new Builder().baseUrl(API_BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
    builder = addConverterFactory;
    retrofit = addConverterFactory.build();
}

public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
    return createService(serviceClass, null, null);
}

public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, String username, String password) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username) || TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        return createService(serviceClass, null);
    }
    return createService(serviceClass, Credentials.basic(username, password));
}

public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, String authToken) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(authToken)) {
        AuthenticationInterceptor interceptor = new AuthenticationInterceptor(authToken);
        if (!httpClient.interceptors().contains(interceptor)) {
            httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor);
            builder.client(httpClient.build());
            retrofit = builder.build();
        }
    }
    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
}
```