# Timeout exception is not fired in retrofit android

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have one api that retrives a huge data , I set the timeout to 7 min no more than that.
So when the waiting time exceeds 7 min I want the operation to be cancelled

However , the users sometimes wait till 10 min and more ..

Below is the code

```
   final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(connectTimeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(readTimeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
```

What I'm missing here?

Comment: what is the value in readTimeOut?

Comment: may be this link will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380844/how-to-set-timeout-in-retrofit-library

Comment: @AbdulWaheed 420

Comment: @Rahul any solution or update???

Answer (score 0):

Connection timeOut is the time to establish a connection and read/writeTimeout is the time required to read or write after establishing connection. so finally

```
totalTimeout = connectTimeOut + readTimeout
```

Your httpClient taking extra time in connectionEstablishment or readTimOut. You have to configure this two timeout in a way that user need not to wait more than your defined time. Please accept my answer if is satisfactory

> Note: All the operation takes less or equal time you defined to
> complete.

For your better understanding visit this link
[Http Client Time Out Guide](https://www.baeldung.com/okhttp-timeouts)

Comment: So in the code snippet the value of connection timeout is 7 min and read timeout is 7 min so total is 14 min but some users wait to 30 min , How is that possible?