# Android Retrofit 2: Programmatically increase timeout by 10 seconds

Tags: android, api, retrofit2

There is a situation where if my API call fails due timeout, I have to retry by increasing the timeout by 20 seconds. All the examples of retrofit I searched show static timeout. Something like in following
[How to set timeout in Retrofit library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380844/how-to-set-timeout-in-retrofit-library)

or ask to put timeout in **@Headers** field. But this is not suitable in my case. **onFailure()**, I want to

1. increase the timeout by 20 seconds for retry attempt and then
2. reset to original timeout.

Comment: Using the link you provided, would it possible to recreate a new HTTP client with the new timeout value?

Comment: Set the timeout in the `OkHttpClient` that you use to create your `Retrofit` instance. When you need to increase the timeout, use `newBuilder()` on the `OkHttpClient` and create a new `OkHttpClient` with all your old settings and the higher timeout. Then, create a new `Retrofit` instance from the new `OkHttpClient`, and use that for the higher-timeout call. When you are done with it, you can dispose of the new `Retrofit` and new `OkHttpClient` -- there will be nothing to "reset", because your original objects are untouched.

Comment: This is a nice idea. However, is there any example or link for reference?